# Selenium webDriver for PrimeFaces pickList component

Tags: selenium, primefaces, webdriver, picklist

Selenium webDriver for PrimeFaces pickList component.

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/pickList.xhtml

Trying to move an item from source list to target list:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.doubleClick(sourceElement).build().perform();
```

Also tried:

```
sourceElement.click();  // select
addButtonElement.click();   // move to right
```

Tried 100 times. About 50 times worked. The rest 50 times: the item was moved to the target list, then it was moved back to the source list.

I suspect it might be due to race condition. The pickList widget itself might be in the process of initializing itself such as binding events. Looked at the pickList javascript code, wait for its init() to complete. That is, check if events have been bound to buttons(add,remove,...). e.g.

```
 ExpectedCondition<Boolean> condition = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            return (Boolean)executor.executeScript(
                    "return jQuery._data(arguments[0], 'events')['click'] != undefined;", addButtonElement);
        }
    };

    wait.until(condition);  

    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.doubleClick(sourceElement).build().perform();
```

But it did not help.

PickList widget code:

https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/2686074/

Comment: These components can be difficult to selenium test because of the JS and Ajax.  There is this cool project: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-arquillian . But they don't have have a Picklist tester YET but always looking for donations!